# :cnext / :cprevious without jumping to location

Tags: quickfix

I've got a pretty large log file with some info interleaved with some errors / warnings and I would like to go to the next error in my quickfix window but without jumping to that location in the code.

At the moment I've got a dirty hack that basically consist in doing `:cnext <C-o>` but that's not ideal.

Any cleaner alternative ? 
I was thinking about something with `getqflist` and `setqflist` to get the current position and increment it, but I have only managed to go to the next line in the log (Which might just be plain text), whereas I want the next error. (So I probably need to iterate over the valid entries in the quickfix window but I haven't figured out how to do that yet)

Answer (score 2):

```
function! s:next_error()
  let wv = winsaveview()
  keepjumps cnext
  call winrestview(wv)
  copen
endfunction
```

the only problem of your approach is that it changed the [:h jumplist](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#jumplist) , you can use [:h :keepjumps](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3Akeepjumps) to avoid that. But your cursor position still get changed after `keepjump cnext`, you window might also get scrolled, to restore that, use [:h winsaveview()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#winsaveview%28%29) and [:h winrestview()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#winrestview%28%29) .

---

It's unpleasent to do this with `getqflist()`:

```
function! s:next_error2()

  " return if current qflist empty
  let qfl = getqflist()
  if empty(qfl)
    return
  endif

  " find next valid error
  let idx = getqflist({'idx':0}).idx
  let next_idx = 0
  while idx < len(qfl)
    if qfl[idx].valid
      let next_idx = idx + 1
      break
    endif
    let idx += 1
  endwhile

  " return if there has no next valid error
  if !next_idx
    return
  endif

  " open qf, jump to next error line
  copen
  exe next_idx
endfunction
```

Note that this approach jump to next `valid` error, i'm not sure if it's exactly the same as `cnext`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new enough version of Vim which supports `getqflist()`/`setqflist()` with the `idx` option then you can directly change the current index without jumping.

Example changing the index to `10`:

```
:call setqflist([], 'a', {'idx': 10})
```

This can be wrapped into a commands to make it easier:

```
command! Csilentnext call setqflist([], 'a', {'idx': get(getqflist({'idx':0}), 'idx', 0)+1})
command! Csilentprev call setqflist([], 'a', {'idx': get(getqflist({'idx':0}), 'idx', 0)-1})
```

Comment: Those `get(getqflist({'idx':1})`s should be `get(getqflist({'idx':0})` or else it only ever returns the index for the 1st value in the dictionary (namely: 1).

Comment: Not only that, but this just scrolls through the lines in the quickfix window. It doesn't jump to the next line that's actually been matched as a quickfix error/warning/etc.